# Transparent SOCKS5 proxy for linux using dual stack IPv4 and IPv6

Tags: proxy, ipv6, ipv4, socks

Can you recommend a SOCKS5 proxy for linux that can accept IPv4 requests, but connects to the internet using dual stack (IPv4 and IPv6)?

It is going to run on Ubuntu with dual stack enabled.

I thought of squid, but how does it have to be configured?
Is there any easier tool than squid? I just want it to be transparent and maybe use authentication.

Answer (score 1):

[srelay](http://socks-relay.sourceforge.net/) claims to support both IPv6 and IPv4.